# Simple CMS for .Net Webshop

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

Im not sure if this is the correct forum for this, if not I apologize. Here goes: Im trying to develop a webshop that should be very simple for the users. Simply add products, create pages, some kind of payment methods and order status. It shoulde also be fairly easy to set up new webshops. Im am currently trying to do this in Umbraco, but this is truly not as easy as i was hoping. Once you start to add custom sections with different modals etc etc it gets kind a complex. My qustion is simply this, is Umbraco a good choice for a simple webshop or should I change to some other underlying .NET CMS? Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is classic example of selection of wrong tool. Umbraco basically a CMS rather than ECom.
I will suggest to use nopcommerce http://www.nopcommerce.com from basic to profession purpose. Works great!!!
I am not promoting either of them; I am big fan of Umbraco, but you have to judge your own decisions for productivity and quick turn around.

Sanjay

Comment: how easy is it to set up new webshops? something a guy in a salesdepartment could hadle if he got som instructions?

Comment: Hi Martin, I have used their code (as is) couple of time for demo to clients, and it works like a charm. They have couple of inbuilt stores, bunch of products and variants. They have built in payment channels and manual checkout options. If it is really simple implementation I think out of box you will a lot than what you are really required. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I wouldn't suggest developing an e-commerce solution yourself. There are many platforms that you could use. For Umbraco you could look at the [uCommerce plugin](http://www.ucommerce.dk/).

If you do want to develop your own e-commerce solution, do you need a CMS at all? Most pages will display some catalog-related content that doesn't involve a CMS. If you do need a CMS, I personally like [Telerik's Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/). It allows you to use editable content elements in your site more freely than Umbraco. Basically, Umbraco is a CMS where you can add custom code, and with Sitefinity you create custom code where you can include CMS elements (which is preferable for sites with a lot of customization).

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco is a great CMS and is extremely configurable! There are a few e-Commerce umbraco packages available in the community:

http://our.umbraco.org/search?q=commerce&content=project

Unfortunately eCommerce sites aren't always "simple" due to the nature of what they are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of Umbraco and uCommerce is great way to build a simple webshop and grow with it. While nopCommerce is a great option it doesn't have the content management piece, which is what makes Umbraco/uCommerce unique and really easy to build and maintain in the long run.

You can use Razor to build your e-commerce solution in Umbraco, which is very cool way of combining .NET code and HTML interchangeably. Razor is really a wonderful way to build websites. Makes the whole process very enjoyable :)

Here's some [information on how to build webshops with Razor](http://www.publicvoid.dk/BuildingWebshopsWithUmbracoRazorAndTheUCommerceEcommerceFrameworkOhMy.aspx).

My two cents.