# ASP.NET open source webshop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webshop

Do anyone has any good tip on a good ASP.NET open source webshop?

I thinking about createing a own webshop and but its bad to create all from the beginning if there is any good open source tool for it...

Please give some tip.

Answer (score 5):

I have used a good open source web shop for my test, it was nopcommerce: http://www.nopcommerce.com/
It's really good and simple to setup.

You can take a look to this SO question too: [Simple CMS for .Net Webshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840244/simple-cms-for-net-webshop)